# Unable to Load Persisted WorkFlow Instance in WorkFlowApplication Host - WF 4.5

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4.5

I am trying to Load a persisted Workflow in order to resume a Bookmark in my process but I keep getting the error: "An instance ID has been generated for the WorkflowApplication because the 'Id' property was read. WorkflowApplication cannot be used to load an instance once an ID has been generated."  I am using Windows Workflow 4.5.  The workflow creation works and the records are correctly persisted in the SQL database but the resume fails when I try to load the instance.  Please can you help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by having Instance.Id in the Watch Window of Visual Studio.